# load a default url delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe3

i would like to load a default URL on form create event, i can load a url using a button click but i want it to load the URL when the app loads, when i run the program it wont load the url.

here is my code :

```
 unit launcher;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Imaging.pngimage, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.OleCtrls, SHDocVw;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    Button1: TButton;
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

 procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  begin
 Webbrowser1.Navigate('http://www.digitalxeon.net');
 end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
close;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Does your FormCreate event even run? Set a breakpoint and see if it fires. As far as I know, if you call Navigate in an OnCreate handler, the page will load. Why tag XE2 and XE3? Which is it?

Comment: i try on both XE2 and XE3 and it does the same , wont load on FormCreate.

Comment: You did not answer all of my questions

Comment: is not running, i have another app i made where i load a .jpg into an image control  from a url on FormCreate and it triggers the event . dont understand why is now working with a TWebBroser and FormCreate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you report is not the whole story. Take the following steps:

1. Create a new VCL forms project.
2. Add a `TWebBrowser` component to the automatically generated form.
3. Double click on the form to create an `OnCreate` event handler named `FormCreate` that is associated with the `OnCreate` event.
4. Put your call to `WebBrowser1.Navigate` into the body of the `FormCreate` method.
5. Run your application and observe that the browser control displays your page.

In other words, something else in your application is blocking this. Perhaps the `OnCreate` event handler is not assigned to `FormCreate`. Or perhaps something else is wrong. However, you can follow the steps above to prove to yourself that navigating from `OnCreate` works. Then all the remains is to diagnose where your application differs.

The bottom line is that calling `Navigate` from an `OnCreate` event is sufficient to show a web page on form startup.

Comment: remove all code i wrote by hand and followed your steps in the same form and it worked.